# JavaScript: Rotate img on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, rotation

I'm trying to make the img with the id image rotate using the onclick event handler to use the code in my function which grabs the image by ID assigns a variable name, then uses the variable name to rotate. I'm not really sure where i when wrong in my code.

```
   <section id="middle">
    <img id="image" src="images/flower.png" >   
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </section>

MyFunction(){
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you have `onclick="myFunction()"` and `MyFunction(){`.  Case matters.  You probably just want `onclick=MyFunction`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Not sure how i missed that!

Comment: One of the errors was not having the key word function in front of the MyFunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the rotation itself using CSS:

```
.rotated-image {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
          transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

On the html:

```
<section id="middle">
    <img id="image" src="images/flower.png" >   
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</section>
```

And then, on the javascript, just add the class:

```
function myFunction() {
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  img.setAttribute("class", "rotated-image");
}
```

Check out the result: http://jsbin.com/ibEmUFI/2/edit

Comment: Thank you I'm playing with this code now. trying to get the img with the ID image to rotate instead of the button it self.

Answer (score 0):

try to use div with id as a selector:

```
<div id='image'><img src="images/flower.png" /></div>

 and 

var img = document.getElementById("image").getElementsByTagName('img');
```

worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rotate` to, well, rotate.

> The `rotate` CSS property allows you to specify rotation transforms individually and independently of the transform property. This maps better to typical user interface usage, and saves having to remember the exact order of transform functions to specify in the transform property.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate)

```js
const rotate = () => {
  document.querySelector("p").classList.add("rotate160deg");
}
```

```css
.rotate160deg {
  rotate: 160deg;
}

// demo related stuff:
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotate {
  transition: rotate 1s;
}
```

```html
You can do the rotation itself using CSS:
<button onclick="rotate()">rotate</button>

<div>
  <p class="rotate"></p>
</div>
```

And we use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add a class to the list of class.