# Rotate button [HTML] [JS]

Tags: javascript, html

how to make a button with javascript when the user presses it to rotate an object 180 moires? (for my site)

```
<input type="button" value="button">
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799846/javascript-rotate-img-on-click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply css3 rotate and onclick event:
https://jsfiddle.net/xxarLyc6/

One class and default rotate:

```
div{
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.rotated{
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Javascript onclick event for button:

```
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("torotate").className = "rotated";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 rotate property how this:

HTML:

`<input type="button" value="button" id="button">`

CSS:

`.rotate-180 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}`

JS:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("rotate-180");
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/1x84r9p6/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Web Animations API (chrome, firefox, and opera all partially support it):

[Simplest Reference](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36) on how to use.

For your code this would do:

```
element.animate([{transform: "rotate(0deg)"}, {transform: "rotate(100deg)"}], {duration: 2000});
```