# How to style nested comments that pulls data from database?

Tags: ajax, html-table, coding-style

I want a section to like Facebook comment system. Users will communicate each other. A user can send a post, the others can send comments.

- Post
- Comment1
- Comment2

  - Comment2.1
  - Comment2.2

    - Comment2.2.1
- Comment3
- Comment3.1

  - Comment3.1.1

Firstly, I created a web service that I can pull data from a database. 
I use this web service with ajax to display my data.
For displaying data, I use `table`, but using table is not good solution. Because my all design is floating when I open the nested comments.
Is there another suggestion instead of `<td><tr> <table>`?

```
function GetComments(postid) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/arayuzService.asmx/GetComments",
            data: '{"postid":"' + postid + '"}',
            success: function (data) {
                var received= jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                var posts = received;
                var strPosts = "";
    $.each(posts, function (index, a) {              
              strPosts += '<tr><td>' + a.userId + '</td></tr>';
           strPosts += "<tr><td><div id='Comment" + a.id + "'></div></td></tr>";

                });

                $("#postComment" + postid).html(strPosts);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: There are probably many different ways you could do it. Why not find a site which does this kind of thing and copy the principles of their markup and CSS? You can easily copy it by inspecting the HTML of the page in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: but i am new. I need pure samples.

Comment: The best kind of sample is a working site. Besides we don't give out free solutions from nothing on this site. We fix bugs with existing code. Once you researched and tried it for yourself, and posted your attempt here, we will try to fix any problems with it. You won't get people making effort to answer if you just ask for a whole feature like this with no evidence of any effort from you. If you're not confident enough about HTML/CSS to have a basic idea of how you could do it, you need to study some more, rather than just receive a working solution on a plate - that won't teach you anything.

Comment: That's true. I agree with you. But what is the description of bug ? Why isn't this a bug ? I tried and the style is floating. May be someone say "add property to table". Is it a bug? I will try what you say. But i cannot understand the site's strict rules. I got a membership of Sharepoint Community Stackoverflow too. I can ask everything what i want.And never banned , downvoted .  I ask what way i should do. They always helped me and finizhed my work. Why are they different?

Comment: There isn't a bug here because you haven't tried anything. You say you want to do it without tables, so you seem to be aware that it could be done a different way using other kinds of HTML. But then you don't seem to have done anything about that in order to find out details of what you could do, or try and make it work. You just gave up and asked someone else to completely re-write your HTML for you, or to suggest to you what do to. Well, I've made my suggestion - look for a site that does this and copy it. I won't write this whole different setup from the beginning for you.

Comment: And no-one has downvoted you or voted to close the question btw, so not sure why you're complaining about that

Comment: I stucked and did not find any way. I should have got a right to ask it. My code is not working. I believe whenever you stuck and your code is not working , you have to got rights to ask. Actually i need an idea . It is a sentence. Only one sentence may be helpful for me. I don't want long-write codes from anybody. When you stuck , draw circles  what do you do?

Comment: On the other hand thank you for your suggestion. I will try inspect element. ı did not ever think this. You remembered to me. Is it bad ? you helped me.

Comment: So i have found it.. is it a bug ? User wanted an advice. the others wrote code for help. What a lazy user , isn't he?                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799846/javascript-rotate-img-on-click